# Problem about creating an empty vector in a class delegating constructor

Tags: c++, class, c++11, vector, constructor

I can create an empty vector like:

```
std::vector<std::string> svec;
```

Now I'm trying to write a delegating constructor for the `Book` class:

```
class Book {
public:
    Book(): Book("", "", std::vector<std::string> svec, 0, "", 1){}
    
    Book(const std::string &i, const std::string &n,
         const std::vector<std::string> &au,
         unsigned y, const std::string &p = "", unsigned v = 1)
            : isbn(i), name(n), author(au),
              publish_year(y), publisher(p), version(v) {}
    }
```

In the above code the first constructor (which is the default constructor) is delegating to the second one. I want to provide the delegated constructor with an empty vector as an argument in the same way I create the empty vector before. However, the compiler shows an error here:

```
Expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction
```

And then I was suggested to use `std::vector<std::string> ()` instead and it works!
My questions:

1. Why I can use `std::vector<std::string> svec` create an empty vector while cannot in the class constructor?
2. How to explain the format `std::vector<std::string> ()`? what does it do or how is it executed?

Answer (score 0):

Just write for example

```
Book(): Book("", "", {}, 0, "", 1){}
```